# Getting Access denied message in command prompt

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, python, home-directory

I recently installd python on my system and am trying to make a directory for python files in my Windows 8.1 system using the command prompt. When I write the following simple command in cmd,

```
 mkdir xyz
```

I get a reply - **Access is denied**.

What is the problem here?

Comment: do you have permission to create folders in the directory you want to create the folder?

Comment: how do I know which is the current working directory in cmd?

Comment: the path on the left hand side of the command you enter. like: 
`C:\WINDOWS\system32> mkdir xyz` but if you specify mkdir like this: `mkdir C:\somepath\newfolder`you need permission in `somepath` to create the `newfolder` there

Comment: Thanks! At first I was typing the first command. I tried the second command and it perfectly worked. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `write` permission on the folder where you want to create your subfolder in.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> mkdir xyz
```

for this command you need write permission in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> mkdir C:\somepath\xyz
```

for this command you need write permission in `C:\somepath`

Comment: Can we make directories only on C drive? I tried making one in another drive. The folder gets created but I am not able to change the directory using `cd` command.

Comment: to change the directory, you just write the letter like this: `D:`. after that you can `cd` inside `D:` like `cd D:\somepath\somefolder`

Comment: Yes, I tried that earlier but in vain. However, `cd /d D:\somepath\somefolder` worked.